# How do you put your own CA into the trusted root CA store of users who are not members of your domain?

Tags: certificate-authority

Suppose I want to use EAP-TLS or EAP-MSCHAPv2 for 802.1x authentication for my wireless network users who are not part of my domain. Is there any way to make your CA trusted by the users other than to manually put it in the trusted store of every single device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend against this. Adding your certificate to personal devices root stores is a bad security practice. It's a matter of trust. Should your corporate devices trust your authority? Yes. Should random peoples devices trust your authority? Not really. The worst that I've seen happen when I've connected to an 802.1x wifi network is it ask me if I want to continue with an unverifiable certificate.

[image: iOS untrusted 802.1x certificate]

In regards to your question though, you need to have a way of distributing the CA certificate before a user connects. For iOS you can create a provisioning profile that contains your CA cert. All you would need to do is have users go to the profile URL in safari and install it.

Android as far as I know is more complicated. Users would need to first download the CA cert, then go into their setting and manually add it.

Automatically allowing CA certificates to be installed is impossible. If it were allowed, attackers could force you to install their own CA certificate and hijack sites like Google or your bank.

Photo source: http://www.bu.edu/tech/services/infrastructure/networks/wireless/8021x/iphone/

Comment: So there isn't actually any practical way to implement EAP-TLS or EAP-MSCHAv2 on non-domain users? (I mean other than using an expensive third party certificate)

Comment: @ZouzouIbba The user will simply be asked if they're sure they want to connect. I'll update my post with an image of how this looks.

Comment: Okay so it is a very bad security practice? In that case what else is there to do? Can I for example get a third party CA to just give one single certificate to my own Subordinate CA and then that Subordinate CA can issue certificates to clients?

Comment: @ZouzouIbba Thats not necessary as the certificate is only for the RADIUS server, not each client. If you were to go a third party CA route, all you would need to do is have a certificate issued for the RADIUS server and clients wouldn't prompt for accepting the certificate. However verification of the certificate is only an issue on initial connect. Once you press the accept button, the device will remember the certificate and allow subsequent connections provided you don't change the cert.

Comment: But if I want to implement EAP-TLS and issue client certificates, then can I get a third party CA to issue one certificate to my own CA which will itself then distribute client certificates?

Comment: @ZouzouIbba I'm not too familiar with using third party CAs to issue client certificates. However using EAP-TLS would require that users have setup their devices before attempting connection, which will bring you back to having to manually install certificates on users devices.

Comment: @ZouzouIbba IronWifi has a good guide on setting up their EAP-TLS service, perhaps it'll provide an insight as to how the process works. https://www.ironwifi.com/documentation/clients/apple-ios-tls/  Note how their certificate is still shown as not verified even though you installed their profile, that's due to them not including their root certificate in the profile for security purposes.

Comment: Holy crap I didn't even know that. I'm just learning about it. So in the end what's your recommendation on how to authenticate non-domain clients to the network with 802.1X? Does EAP-MSCHAPv2 also require each client device to be configured?

Comment: @ZouzouIbba EAP-MSCHAPv2 only requires a username and password, usually the users domain login. This allows the user to connect a device on their own without assistance. My recommendation is based on how hardened you need your network to be. If you want to allow domain users to use the wifi for their personal devices, use EAP-MSCHAPv2. If you want it so that only verified devices can access, use EAP-TLS.

Comment: But what about non-domain users?

Comment: @ZouzouIbba Most corporate offices have a separate guest network for that purpose. Domain users are more of seen as employees who have access to special resources on the internal network. A guest network would allow for non authorized individuals to access the internet without exposing your internal network.

Comment: I know but suppose it's a campus where you only want registered students to get access to the network and not strangers.

Comment: @ZouzouIbba There's multiple paths to achieve this. You could create an organizational unit that contains users who are only allowed to authenticate on the network. You can try to configure a RADIUS server to hit multiple sources to verify the users. I myself have no experience with making a RADIUS server do that, so I won't be able to help you there.